# Haskell - Removing adjacent duplicates from a list

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, fold

I'm trying to learn haskell by solving some online problems and training exercises.

Right now I'm trying to make a function that'd remove adjacent duplicates from a list.

> Sample Input
>
> "acvvca"
>
> "1456776541"
>
> "abbac"
>
> "aabaabckllm"
>
> ---
>
> Expected Output
>
> ""
>
> ""
>
> "c"
>
> "ckm"

My first though was to make a function that'd simply remove first instance of adjacent duplicates and restore the list.

```
module Test where

removeAdjDups :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
removeAdjDups []           =  []
removeAdjDups [x]          =  [x]
removeAdjDups (x : y : ys)
  | x == y = removeAdjDups ys
  | otherwise = x : removeAdjDups (y : ys)
```

---

```
*Test> removeAdjDups "1233213443"
"122133"
```

---

This func works for first found pairs.

So now I need to apply same function over the result of the function.

Something I think foldl can help with but I don't know how I'd go about implementing it.

Something along the line of

```
removeAdjDups' xs = foldl (\acc x -> removeAdjDups x acc) xs
```

---

Also is this approach the best way to implement the solution or is there a better way I should be thinking of?

Comment: Wouldn't something similar to Unix `uniq` be more common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start in last-first order: first remove duplicates from the tail, then check if head of the input equals to head of the tail result (which, by this moment, won't have any duplicates, so the only possible pair is head of the input vs. head of the tail result):

```
main = mapM_ (print . squeeze) ["acvvca", "1456776541", "abbac", "aabaabckllm"]

squeeze :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
squeeze (x:xs) = let ys = squeeze xs in case ys of
                                            (y:ys') | x == y -> ys'
                                            _ -> x:ys
squeeze _ = []
```

Outputs

```
""
""
"c"
"ckm"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. If you pass `"vacvvca"`, the `v` in head position should be elided too.

Comment: How exactly? Can you give a definition of 'adjacent duplicates' that would allow such interpretation?

Comment: What do you mean by 'elided' by the way?

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood, but by the same token that `ac` and `ca` are adjacent dupes in the `acvvca` string.

Comment: agh, I meant removed.

Comment: So, can you define those duplicates you're speaking of?

Comment: I understood 'adjacent duplicates' as 'next to each other', but looking at the examples above it looks like it means 'a contiguous list of characters repeated in any order'; in which case your definition is exactly that. ha! I should have read twice.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how `foldl` could be used for this. (Generally, `foldl` pretty much combines the disadvantages of `foldr` and `foldl'`... those, or `foldMap`, are the folds you should normally be using, not `foldl`.)

What you seem to intend is: *repeating* the `removeAdjDups`, until no duplicates are found anymore. The repetition is a job for

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

like

```
Prelude> iterate removeAdjDups "1233213443"
["1233213443","122133","11","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""...
```

This is an infinite list of ever reduced lists. Generally, it will *not* converge to the empty list; you'll want to add some termination condition. If you want to remove as many dups as necessary, that's the *fixpoint*; it can be found in a very similar way to how you implemented `removeAdjDups`: compare neighbor elements, just this time in the list of *reductions*.

[bipll's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386171/745903) to handle recursive duplicates is much better though, it avoids unnecessary comparisons and traversing the start of the list over and over.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are often overlooked. They are, of course syntactic sugar but some, like me are addicted. First off, strings are lists as they are. This functions could handle any list, too as well as singletons and empty lists. You can us map to process many lists in a list.

```
(\l -> [ x  | (x,y) <- zip l $ (tail l) ++ " ", x /= y]) "abcddeeffa"
```

"abcdefa"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see either how to use `foldl`. It's maybe because, if you want to fold something here, you have to use `foldr`.

```
main = mapM_ (print . squeeze) ["acvvca", "1456776541", "abbac", "aabaabckllm"]

-- I like the name in @bipll answer
squeeze = foldr (\ x xs -> if xs /= "" && x == head(xs) then tail(xs) else x:xs) ""
```

Let's analyze this. The idea is taken from @bipll answer: go from right to left. If `f` is the lambda function, then by definition of `foldr`:

```
squeeze "abbac" = f('a' f('b' f('b' f('a' f('c' "")))
```

By definition of `f`, `f('c' "") = 'c':"" = "c"` since `xs == ""`. Next char from the right: `f('a' "c") = 'a':"c" = "ac"` since `'a' != head("c") = 'c'`.  `f('b' "ac") = "bac"` for the same reason. But `f('b' "bac") = tail("bac") = "ac"` because `'b' == head("bac")`. And  so forth...

Bonus: by replacing `foldr` with `scanr`, you can see the whole process:

```
Prelude> squeeze' = scanr (\ x xs -> if xs /= "" && x == head(xs) then tail(xs) else x:xs) ""
Prelude> zip "abbac" (squeeze' "abbac")
[('a',"c"),('b',"ac"),('b',"bac"),('a',"ac"),('c',"c")]
```