# How does `until` work?

Tags: haskell

I wanted to answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385950/haskell-removing-adjacent-duplicates-from-a-list) using `until`. But that does not work and I've concluded that I don't understand `until`.

So I take the function given by the OP, verbatim:

```
removeAdjDups :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
removeAdjDups []           =  []
removeAdjDups [x]          =  [x]
removeAdjDups (x : y : ys)
  | x == y = removeAdjDups ys
  | otherwise = x : removeAdjDups (y : ys)
```

Then I write a `True/False` function retuning whether there is a duplicate:

```
hasAdjDups :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
hasAdjDups []           =  False
hasAdjDups [x]          =  False
hasAdjDups (x : y : ys)
  | x == y = True
  | otherwise = hasAdjDups (y : ys)
```

Finally I use `until` as follows:

```
f :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
f x = until hasAdjDups removeAdjDups x
```

And that does not work :

```
> hasAdjDups  "aabccddcceef"
True
> removeAdjDups   "aabccddcceef"
"bf"
> f "aabccddcceef"
"aabccddcceef"
```

I misunderstand `until`, or I did a mistake ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [**`until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:until) is documented as:

> `until p f` yields the result of **applying `f` until `p` holds**.

It is implemented like:

> ```
> until p f = go
>   where
>     go x | p x          = x
>          | otherwise    = go (f x)
> ```

So you provide a predicate `p`, and a function `f`. The function is also given an initial value `x`. By using recursion, it first checks if `p x` holds. In case it does, it returns `x`, otherwise, it makes a recursive call with `f x` as the new `x`.

So a more clean (but less efficient) implementation is probably:

```
until p f x | p x = x
            | otherwise = until p f (f x)
```

If we analyze your function, we see:

```
f x = until hasAdjDups removeAdjDups x
```

So that means `f` will terminale removing adjacent duplicate characters from the moment it *has* adjacent duplicate characters. You probably want the opposite predicate:

```
f x = until (not . hasAdjDups) removeAdjDups x
```

Or even shorter:

```
f = until (not . hasAdjDups) removeAdjDups
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably forgetting a `not`:

```
f :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
f x = until (not . hasAdjDups) removeAdjDups x

f "aabccddcceef" -- "bf"
```

Comment: Rhhooo, stupid of me. Thanks! I believed that `until` meant "until this condition is True, then apply this function".

Comment: That's exactly what it means. So if your function reurns true immediately it doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: Yes, it does work like that. So until "not has duplicates, apply this function" and then you will be left with something that hasn't got duplicates.

Comment: Yes sorry, I just realize that what it means. I had a bad French translation of *until* in fact...

Answer (score 3):

Well, `until` repeatedly applies the transformation to the value *until* the predicate matches. In your case, the input already `hasAdjDups`, so `removeAdjDups` is never called. You might be looking for `while`:

```
while = until . (not .)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a `while´ in Haskell.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I don't know either. Turns out, there isn't. Oops.

Comment: I find `while` more natural. Maybe it's a question of habit. I've never seen `until` in another language.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: several languages have one (like bash, perl), but indeed `while` is more popular. Although that can simply be historical (i.e. more languages implemented `while` in the first place, and as a result there was less reason to implement an `until` in new ones). After all the two are "twins".

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Pascal has (had?) both `repeat .. until condition` and `while condition do ...` statements. `while` stops when the condition is false, `until` stops when the condition is true. In the same language, two different conventions. In more modern languages, the usual idiom is that loops stop on a false condition.